# Emitting values from ktable and modifying it

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to solve the following problem with kafka.
There is a topic. let's call it src-topic. I receive records from this topic from time to time. I would like to store those values in a ktable and emit the values stored in the ktable every 10 seconds to dst-topic. When I emit a value from this ktable for the first time then I want to append 1 to the record I emit. Every subsequent time I would like to append 0 to the emitted record.

I'm looking for a correct and preferably idiomatic solution to this issue.
One of the solutions I see is to emit a record with 1 appended when I ingest from src-topic and then store in the ktable the record with 0 appended. Another thread will be reading from this ktable and emitting the records regularly. The problem with this approach is that it has a race condition.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: "emit the values stored in the ktable every 10 seconds to dst-topic" can you clarify this. Do you want to emit all values that are currently contained in the table, emit every 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes. All values from the ktable.

Comment: I am wondering what you try to accomplish from a more high level point of view...

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight forward way to do this. Note, a `KTable` is a changelog *stream* (it might have a table state internally -- not all KTables do have a state --, but that's an implementation detail).

Thus, a `KTable` is a stream and you cannot flush a stream... And because the state (if there is any) is internal, you cannot flush the state either.

You can only access the state via Interactive Queries that also allow to do a range scan. However, this will not emit anything downstream but gives the data to the "non Streams part" of you application.

I think, you will need to use low-level Processor API to get the result you want.